# Binding ObservableCollection of strings to templated ListBox

Tags: wpf, templates, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have this collection

```
ObservableCollection<string> Urls { get; set; }
```

inside my data context class. I have a binding to it in my list box:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Urls}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

The data is diplayed in the list box, the two corresponding-not-shown-here buttons with commands Add and Delete work as well, however, the changing the `TextBox` does not affect the contents of the collection.

I have tried `Mode=TwoWay` in binding, but I figured that it is turned on already. I have tried some other options like Validate=OnPropertyChange, however, there is still nothing get updated.

How to make the `TextBox` inside that templated items in `ListBox` actually update the `Urls` property of a datacontext class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot modify strings; use a wrapper class with one string property, then bind the `TextBox` to said property. That way the strings in the property can be replaced with the edited ones.